# Is it possible to get an aggregated list of friend news activities for a particular app which you and your friend has added using FQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created an app that will capture user news article read actions once the user has added the application. I know it is possible to use FQL to return a list of my friends who have also added the app. What I require though, is to get an aggregated list of friends' news read activity, much like Yahoo News does it.

Iteration through all my friends who have added the app and doing a graph request to get their read actions seems quite resource intensive, thus my question on if it is possible getting this info via a single FQL query, or even two seperate queries, rather than doing this iteration.

Comment: As a side note, I have noticed using the graph api, doing an HTTP GET to https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/[app_namespace]:read returns an empty data list. I have had a friand add the app and read an article, but the data list remains empty. Any ideas?